# Why does timezone_name_from_abbr return an empty string?

Tags: php, timezone

Why does the following return an empty string:

```
$offset = -10; //UM10

echo timezone_name_from_abbr('', $offset * 3600, true); //empty string
```

I am using PHP 5.3.0.

Thanks all for any help.

Comment: Perhaps there's no named-timezone in -10 that does daylight savings? try removing the 'true' parameter so that DST isn't taken into consideration while searching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you set the daylight savings time option to true:

```
$ php -r "echo timezone_name_from_abbr('', -10 * 3600, false);"
Pacific/Honolulu
```

Comment: Hmm, I see +1. How would I know to set DST to false for a timezone that I do not know yet and I am trying to retrieve? Maybe its best if I just ignore DST altogether?

Comment: @Abs hmm, actually http://bugs.php.net/44780 I don't see it assigned a resolved and it matches your issue exactly

Comment: Wow, since 2008. God damn it! I think I'll comment on that bug. Thank you for pointing me to this. I think I'll just rule out DST for now.